# What's the best comunication protocol for a sensor network?

Tags: sensor, wireless, network-interface

What's the best comunication protocol for a fast and cheap wirelless sensor network?

Is it one of these?

WirelessHART

IEEE 1451

ZigBee / 802.15.4

ZigBee IP

6LoWPAN

Other

Comment: Please define best.

Comment: Or at least define *fast* and *cheap*.

Comment: How far apart are the nodes?  How much data will they send?  What environment do the operate in?  Do multiple, logically independent networks in close proximity need to co-exist?

Comment: 10 to 50m, small chunks of data, open air, yes. I'm new at this so sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: More specs are needed such as power consumption, distance, network protocol such as mesh or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those you've listed use 802.15.4 as the physical radio layer.

802.15.4 is a good choice as there are many chips from semiconductor makers that have this radio. Also look into BTLE.

A great way to get started with 802.15.4 and 6lowpan is with the [Contiki Operationg system](http://www.contiki-os.org/) and [Econotags](http://www.redwirellc.com/store/node/1).